Laravel project inside a legacy one
I'm trying to make a laravel project work inside a legacy site while we work on modernizing the entire code base. I've been able to make it work in my dev computer using valet creating a custom valet driver, but I'm struggling to configure apache to work in the same way.
My virtual host config on apache looks like (Edited):
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName "xxxxxxxxxxx:443"
                UseCanonicalName Off

                DocumentRoot "/var/www/xxxx/dev"
                CustomLog /var/log/apache2/xxxx/logs/dev_access_ssl_log combined
                ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/xxxx/logs/dev_error_log"
                Alias /laravel /var/www/xxxx/dev/laravel/public


                <Directory /var/www/xxxx/dev>
                        SSLRequireSSL

                        Options -Includes -ExecCGI

                </Directory>
                <Directory /var/www/xxxx/dev>
                        Options +FollowSymLinks
                </Directory>
                DirectoryIndex "index.html" "index.cgi" "index.pl" "index.php" "index.xhtml" "index.htm" "index.shtml"

                <Directory /var/www/xxxx/dev>
                        AllowOverride All
            # AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=Indexes,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,MultiViews,FollowSymLinks,ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC
                </Directory>
            <Directory /var/www/xxxx/laravel/public>
                AllowOverride All
            </Directory>
      </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

(Edited)
I changed the project structure restoring the default placement for public directory and in my Valet configuration again it works fine.
This is the .htaccess file inside the /laravel/public directory:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laravel
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1  [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

I've added differing from laravel standard htaccess file, a RewriteBase directive in order to make al request stay into /laravel (which is an alias for /laravel/public as per vhost file)
I still get 404 error (blade styled) whenever I try to access something like /laravel/admin (which is a route configured in the web.php file under /routes).
I'm pretty sure I messed up rewriting and redirects but I'm banging my head on it without any advancement.
What I find completely baffling is that on Valet all it takes are 10 lines of code:
    public function frontControllerPath(string $sitePath, string $siteName, string $uri):string
    {
        $ext = pathinfo($uri, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if($ext != '') {
            return $uri = $sitePath.$uri;
        } else {
         if($uri == '/') {
           return $sitePath.'/index.php';
         } elseif (str_contains($uri,'/laravel')) {
           return $sitePath.'/laravel/public/index.php';
         }
         else {
           return $uri == '/admin/' ? $sitePath . '/admin/index.php' : $sitePath. $uri . '.php';
         }
        }
    }


Turns out it was not a rewrite problem.
Or better, it was, but it was not the real problem.
After refactoring the project into the standard one, I had to adjust slightly the .htaccess file from the main legacy project and create a laravel.php file that included only a require_once of the original index.php from the laravel project inside the public.
The main issue was that the two View components were misspelled without the first Capital letter, so basically the blade couldn't find them.
